# Factorising an anti-symmetric polynomial

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Say I have an anti-symmetric polynomial function 
$$f(x,y)=y^{m}-x^{m}$$

Where $m$ is some positive integer. Since it is anti-symmetric, we know that there is at least one way of writing it as a product of anti-symmetric factor $y-x$ with a symmetric function $S(x,y)$ 
$$f(x,y)=(y-x)S(x,y)$$
My question is, for a given $m$ in $y^{m}-x^{m}$, can we know what is highest power of $y-x$ that we can extract from it such that $S(x,y)$ doesn't have any factor of $y-x$ left in it.

Comment: If $y-x$ is a prime then by LTE (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/&ved=2ahUKEwjz58rbluzoAhWb4nMBHUbyCuYQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2RpX2YqqHMZDP_cGE2SHT_)  $\nu_{y-x} (y^m-x^m)=1+\nu_{y-x} (m)$ where $\nu_{p} (x)$ with a prime $p$ is defined to be the higest power of $p$ dividing $x$

Comment: @Shamim There is no constraint on $y-x$ to be a prime. How to approach it then?

Comment: @Shamim It's alright.

Comment: Anyway, you should have $y-x | mx^{m-1}$ as $y^{m-1}+y^{m-2}x+\cdots +x^{m-1}=mx^{m-1} \pmod {y-x}$

Answer (score 1):

$$y^m - x^m = (y-x)\left(y^{m-1} + y^{m-2}x + y^{m-3}x^2 + \ldots + yx^{m-2} + x^{m-1}\right)$$ Setting $y = x$ in the 2nd factor gives $mx^{m-1}$, which is not $0$ (unless we are working in a field where $m\equiv 0$). Therefore it cannot have $y - x$ as a factor.